# JSON is not able to encode the Object type data in Perl

Tags: json, perl, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encode some data in JSON and want to send the JSON encoded data through browser.
But the data contains the OBJECT of Crypt::RSA::Key::Private and not able to encode the same as given below.

CODE:

```
use Crypt::RSA;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON::XS;

my $rsa = Crypt::RSA->new();
my ($public_key, $private_key) = $rsa->keygen( Size => 128 );

print "private_key - " . Dumper($private_key) . "\n" . ref($private_key) . "\n";

my $info = {
    'flag'      => 1,
    'private_key' => $private_key
};

my $json_info = JSON::XS->new->allow_blessed->convert_blessed->encode($info);

print "json_info - " . Dumper($json_info) . "\n";

my $content_hash = JSON::XS->new->allow_blessed->convert_blessed->decode($json_info);
print "content_hash " . Dumper($content_hash) . "\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
private_key - $VAR1 = bless( {
                 'Cipher' => 'Blowfish',
                 'Checked' => 0,
                 'Version' => '1.99',
                 'private' => {
                                '_e' => bless( do{\(my $o = '140486154324192')},         'Math::Pari' ),
                                '_dp' => bless( do{\(my $o = 40289976)}, 'Math::Pari' ),
                                '_d' => bless( do{\(my $o = 40151976)}, 'Math::Pari' ),
                                '_dq' => bless( do{\(my $o = 40290328)}, 'Math::Pari' ),
                                '_phi' => bless( do{\(my $o = 39423832)}, 'Math::Pari' ),
                                '_q' => bless( do{\(my $o = 29831976)}, 'Math::Pari' ),
                                '_p' => bless( do{\(my $o = 29832440)}, 'Math::Pari' ),
                                '_n' => bless( do{\(my $o = 40309624)}, 'Math::Pari' ),
                                '_u' => bless( do{\(my $o = 40290392)}, 'Math::Pari' )
                              }
               }, 'Crypt::RSA::Key::Private' );

Crypt::RSA::Key::Private
json_info - $VAR1 = '{"private_key":null,"flag":1}';

content_hash $VAR1 = {
          'flag' => 1,
          'private_key' => undef
        };
```

private_key should not be null, So am i missing anything in the code which is the reason of above behavior?

Comment: Math::Pari looks like inside-out objects, which you can't peek into thus can't serialize either.

Comment: Math::Pari is internally used by the cryptographer module Crypt::RSA, So any other suggestion for the module which can be used for generating the public/private key and which can be serialized to JSON and also comes with Debian package perl bundle.

Comment: The Perl object simply contains a pointer to a C data structure. Serializing that is useless.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the string representation of the RSA private key, you can serialize it (to binary data) with

```
Crypt::RSA::Key::Private::SSH->serialize( $private_key )
```

and use this module

```
Convert::ASCII::Armour
```

to generate a string representation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but deserialize() is not working as expected.

CODE:
    `my $private_key_serialized =    Crypt::RSA::Key::Private::SSH::serialize( $private_key );
    print "private_key_serialized " . Dumper($private_key_serialized) . "\n";

    my $deserialize_key = Crypt::RSA::Key::Private::SSH::deserialize( $private_key_serialized );
    print "deserialize_key " . Dumper($deserialize_key) . "\n";`

Comment: oh, I didn't test that. I'll try to take a further look later